# Searching DataGridView and Selecting Match

Tags: vb.net, vba

How would I search a DataGridView's first column for a Value and select the row IF the Value is there? -- Much like a WHERE Clause in SQL.

I've been looking around for an answer in threads but I can't seem to find one.

`DataGridView1` is the DataGridView and `My.Settings.CurrentUserID` is the Value I want to search for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note; There can only be one occurrence of the Value in the table, so there is no concern for multiple returns/matches.

{Edit 1}

Steves solution seems to only highlight the row and not actually select it as the Black arrow doesn't move onto it. The value the code's looking for is `4`, notice how it finds it and highlights it, but the arrow doesn't move.

**The code does this:**

[image]

**I need it to do this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well supposing that the column you want to search is the first one then

```
For Each row in DataGridView1.Rows
    If Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells(0).Value) = My.Settings.CurrentUserID Then
        row.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

EDIT:

To indicate the "current" row, set the [CurrentCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the datagridview.

```
   .....
   DataGridView1.CurrentCell = row.Cells(0)
   Exit For
```

From MSDN:

> When you set a cell as the current cell, it will scroll into view if
>   it is not currently displayed. The current cell cannot be a header
>   cell, a disabled cell, or a cell in a hidden row or column.

Comment: Hi Steve, that seems to highligh the row, but it doesn't select it. It like highlights it in Blue but the black arrow on the left doesn't move onto it and when I try to load data from the selected row it takes data from the row that the black arrow is on; by default the first row.

Comment: Thank you VERY much! My problem has been solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a click event or whatever...

```
    Dim intIndex As Integer = FindUser(txtSearchString.Text, txtColumn.Text)
    dgvMembers.CurrentCell = dgvMembers.Rows(intIndex).Cells(0) 'This ensures that the    arrow will move
```

Put this in your class or wherever...

```
  Private Function FindUser(ByVal strUserID As String, ByVal intColumn As Integer) As Integer
    Dim intIndex As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvMembers.Rows.Count - 1
        If dgvMembers.Rows(i).Cells(intColumn).Value.ToString = strUserID Then
            intIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return intIndex
End Function
```

Comment: Works and TESTED it. This way you can tell it what column and what your looking for.