# Caret in column won't move after selecting currentcell in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I read the way you move the row indicator(the little black caret) is by setting the datagridview.currentcell property. When I do this it sets the current cell appropriately, but it still won't move the row indicator. I do this after adding a row to my datagridview.

```
    Private Sub dataGridView_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles dataGridView.RowsAdded
        if(not dataGridView.rows(e.rowindex).isnewrow)
        dataGridView.currentCell = dataGridView.Item(dataGridView.firstDisplayedCell.columnindex, e.rowindex)
        end if
    end sub
```

Comment: So the highlighted (current) cell is on a row other than the one with the black triangle?

Comment: Yes. The highlighted (current) cell is on a row other than the one with the black triangle.

Comment: Other answers say if you want to move the caret. You have to specify the currentcell property which I'm doing but nothing is happening to the caret.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching DataGridView and Selecting Match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499728/searching-datagridview-and-selecting-match)

Comment: There already an answer for that in the link above.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Doesn't seem to work when inside the RowsAdded event handler

Comment: Is fullrowselect set as default?

Comment: Nope. RowHeaderSelect is. I did try switching it to fullrowselect and nothing changed that I liked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, according to how everything gets called. I'm doing this at the wrong spot. In my situation I'm databinding so as soon as something is added to my bindinglist all of this gets called. Maybe I should've mentioned that earlier...

`0 rowunshared
0 rowstatechanged
0 invalidated
0 rowleave
0 rowvalidating
0 rowvalidated
0 invalidated
0 rowstatechanged
0 invalidated
0 rowstatechanged
0 rowenter
2 invalidated
2 invalidated
2 invalidated
2 invalidated
2 invalidated
2 rowstatechanged
2 invalidated
2 rowstatechanged
2 rowsadded
2 rowenter
0 invalidated
0 invalidated
0 invalidated
0 invalidated
0 databindingcomplete`

0 and 2 are rows in the DGV. 0 is the one the caret is currently on; 2 is the just added row. So according to this I shouldn't try to changed the currentcell and instead do it in the databindingcomplete event. I did all this printing by using console.writeline in their respective handlers and the currentcell to see which row was the current one.

```
private sub dataGridView_DataBindingComplete(sender as object, e as DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) handles dataGridView.DataBindingComplete
    if(e.ListChangedType = ListChangedType.ItemAdded)
        dataGridView.currentcell = dataGridView.item(dataGridView.firstDisplayedCell.columnindex, bindingList.count - 1)
    End If
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I got something to work, but it seems like an odd way to do it. It is written in c# but should be applicable to VB. I set up a private class level variable called r that stores the new row index. Before the row is painted, I reset the currentcell to the desired cell and call DGV.Refresh(). This seems to do what you want, but not very pretty.

```
 {
     dataGridView1.RowsAdded += dataGridView1_RowsAdded;
     dataGridView1.RowPrePaint += dataGridView1_RowPrePaint;
 }

 bool temp = false;
 int r;

 void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
 {            
     if (!dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
     {
         r = e.RowIndex;
         dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.ColumnIndex, r];
         temp = true;
     }
 }

 void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
 {
     if (temp)
     {
         temp = false;
         dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.ColumnIndex, r];
         dataGridView1.Refresh();
     }
 }
```

Comment: That is pretty ugly. I did find something interesting you may have already. After assigning the currentcell, immediately calling dgv.refresh() works for a split second then resets back to where it was before. Do you know what would be called after this handler completes? Internally of course.

Comment: @user2567273 I saw the same thing, I don't know what is being called after RowsAdded that is overriding the currentcell.